# Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express server, and I would like to write something like

```
for(p in params)
    app.get("/"+p,function (req, res) {res.send(p)});
```

Now, for params[0], request arrives, but response is params[n-1]

Comment: Show the code of params. I need it to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use anonimous function to make copy of 'p' on each iteration.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var params = {
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 2,
    'c' : 3
};

for (p in params) {
    (function (p) {
        app.get('/' + p, function (req, res) { res.send(p); });
    })(p);
}

http.createServer(app).listen(1339, '0.0.0.0');
```